# Integrating Celo with Chainlink

Tags: chainlink

I have participated in a hackathon. So, we decided to use Celo + Chainlink. But in Chianlink I saw there they don't have any smart contract in CELO network.

Expect:
A chainlink smart contract link like one of these: https://docs.chain.link/resources/link-token-contracts.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there isn't a popular Chainlink network on the Celo network. You could run your own node there if you'd like and [start a network yourself](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/).

Comment: I think as at April, 2023, there is Chainlink network on the Celo network. [Written about it here](https://blog.celo.org/its-finally-here-celo-joins-chainlink-scale-27c26f6bcc2b)